# Replace captured groups with empty string in python

Tags: python, regex

I currently have a string similar to the following:

```
str = 'abcHello Wor=A9ld'
```

What I want to do is find the 'abc' and '=A9' and replace these matched groups with an empty string, such that my final string is 'Hello World'.

I am currently using this regex, which is correctly finding the groups I want to replace:

```
r'^(abc).*?(=[A-Z0-9]+)'
```

I have tried to replace these groups using the following code:

```
clean_str = re.sub(r'^(abc).*?(=[A-Z0-9]+)', '', str)
```

Using the above code has resulted in:

```
print(clean_str)
>>> 'ld'
```

My question is, how can I use re.sub to replace these groups with an empty string and obtain my 'Hello World'?

Comment: Capture what you want to preserve and don't capture what you want to remove. Use a reference to the capture group in the replacement string.

Comment: Maybe you want to replace multiple occurrences of `=[A-Z0-9]+`? Then try `re.sub(r'^abc|=[A-Z0-9]+', '', s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is there a way that I can use your regex, but also ensure that abc is present, otherwise don't replace the second pattern?

Comment: Not with `re`, you need to just check if the string starts with `abc` and then use [`re.sub(r'=[A-Z0-9]+', '', s[3:])`](https://ideone.com/23K52L). Or you may do it with 1 regex if you use *PyPi `regex` module*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I actually used your solution that you have given above: re.sub(r'^abc|=[A-Z0-9]+', '', s)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution was posted as a comment after I accepted solution. If you would like me to accept your solution, post it as a solution.

Comment: I added my answer with 2 solutions: 1) based on Python `re` with 2 steps, 2) a PyPi one based on the infinite width lookbehind pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great explanation, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can .. ensure that `abc` is present, otherwise don't replace the second pattern?

I understand that you need to first check if the string starts with `abc`, and if yes, remove the `abc` and all instances of `=[0-9A-Z]+` pattern in the string.

I recommend:

```
import re
s="abcHello wo=A9rld"
if s.startswith('abc'):
    print(re.sub(r'=[A-Z0-9]+', '', s[3:]))
```

Here, `if s.startswith('abc'):` checks if the string has `abc` in the beginning, then `s[3:]` truncates the string from the start removing the `abc`, and then `re.sub`  removes all non-overlapping instances of the `=[A-Z0-9]+` pattern.

Note you may use [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) to do the same with one regex:

```
import regex
r = regex.compile(r'^abc|(?<=^abc.*?)=[A-Z0-9]+', regex.S)
print(r.sub('', 'abcHello Wor=A9ld=B56')) # Hello World
print(r.sub('', 'Hello Wor=A9ld'))        # => Hello Wor=A9ld
```

See an [online Python demo](http://rextester.com/AOIXFE42907)

Here,

- `^abc`  - `abc` at the start of the string only
- `|` -  or
- `(?<=^abc.*?)` - check if there is `abc` at the start of the input and then any number of chars other than line break chars immediately to the left of the current location
- `=[A-Z0-9]+` - a `=` followed with 1+ uppercase ASCII letters/digits.

Answer (score 4):

Capture everything else and put those groups in the replacement, like so:

```
re.sub(r'^abc(.*?)=[A-Z0-9]+(.*)', r'\1\2', s)
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
re.sub(r'^(abc)(.*?)(=[A-Z0-9]+)(.*?)$', r"\2\4", str)
```

Comment: In this solution, how could I change it so that it would remove multiple instances of (=[A-Z0-9]+) and retain the other text? I would need multiple groups? e.g. this string: 'abcHel=A5lo Wor=A9ld'

Comment: you can achieve that with this `print re.sub(r'^(abc)(.*?)$', r'\2', re.sub(r'(.*?)=[A-Z0-9]+(.*?)', r'\1\2', str))`

Answer (score 1):

This is a naïve approach but why can't you use `replace` twice instead of regex, like this:

```
str = str.replace('abc','')
str = str.replace('=A9','')

print(str) #'Hello World'
```

Comment: `str.replace` won't work because OP needs to get rid of `(=[A-Z0-9]+)` which might not be `=A9`. But `re.sub` twice might work, depending on the exact requirements.

Comment: okay. In the question he has mentioned that, he wants to find the groups 'abc' and '=A9'. This led me to this answer.