# trim string to special charater

Tags: python, string, trim

I have some string in the data frame look like these 'Temp (Â°C)','Dew Point Temp (Â°C)','Rel Hum (%)','Wind Dir (10s deg)'.

How can I trim the the part in the parenthesis and leave only "Temp', 'Dow Point Temp', "Rel Hum', 'Wind Dir'?

Please note I need to deal with special character like 'Â' or other special characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace captured groups with empty string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799965/replace-captured-groups-with-empty-string-in-python)

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do it would be splitting on the first space-open parentheses `(` combo like this

```
a = 'Temp (Â°C)','Dew Point Temp (Â°C)','Rel Hum (%)','Wind Dir (10s deg)', 'column without units'

[i.split(' (')[0] if ' (' in i else i for i in a]
```

which produces

```
['Temp', 'Dew Point Temp', 'Rel Hum', 'Wind Dir', 'column without units']
```

Note that I have included the `if` statement in the list comprehension to take care of names which don't contain any parentheses.